# ios accessing battery current and maximum capacity (mAh)

Tags: ios, battery, capacity

I'm interested in doing some battery diagnostics for an iphone application.  I've seen other apps that are able to display current and maximum battery capacity, to show current battery storage performance.  It's unclear how to get this information in iOS, yet the apps are there and in the app store so it must be possible.

Below is an example of the Battery Health app showing Current maximum capacity and original capacity.

I've read about using IOKit, however that it will also mean automatic app store rejection.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/nst/BatteryChart ?

Comment: Interesting project but a little old at this point.  Uses IOKit and GAIA.framework (OSDBattery), the latter of which seems to have vanished and the former of which is rumored unsupported by App Store still.

Comment: I could not get that project to compile + run in current ios9 environment.